# How to properly handle multiplie key presses in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input

I'm making shortcuts for a little project i'm doing with unity.
In my game i defined two hotkeys :

1 - Shift + Ctrl + G

2 - Shift + G

So my code looks like this:

```
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G))
        {
            DoSomethingA()
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G))
        {
            DoSomethingB()
        }
```

Now when i hold control and shift and press G, `DoSomethingB` executes too, I thought unity has something like Input.GetKeyCount() to check if 2 keys are pressed but seems like unity missing this feature, how can I deal with this situation?

EDIT 1 :
I use this function for easing the process.

```
[Serializable] public struct MultiHotkey2
{
    public KeyCode firstKey;
    public KeyCode secondKey;
}
[Serializable] public struct MultiHotkey3
{
    public KeyCode firstKey;
    public KeyCode secondKey;
    public KeyCode thirdkey;
}

    private bool CheckDoubleHotKey(MultiHotkey2 hotkey2)
    {
        return Input.GetKey(hotkey2.firstKey) && Input.GetKeyDown(hotkey2.secondKey) && GetGlobalUndoRedoSystemState();
    }
    private bool CheckTripleHotKey(MultiHotkey3 hotkey3)
    {
        return Input.GetKey(hotkey3.firstKey) && Input.GetKey(hotkey3.secondKey) && Input.GetKeyDown(hotkey3.thirdkey) && GetGlobalUndoRedoSystemState();
    }
```

Comment: Try `Input.GetKeyDown` or `Input.GetKeyUp`.

Comment: @Serg it doesn't work with LShift LControl holding keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this specific example you may only check if Control Key is not pressed in second if statement, making it look like this:

```
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G) && !Input.GetKey(LeftControl))
    {
        DoSomethingB();
    }
```

Also 'else if' statement would fix it. Solution:

```
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G))
    {
        DoSomethingA();
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G))
    {
        DoSomethingB();
    }
```

Program will skip second 'if statement' if the first requirements are met.

You also can edit the solution a little to make it more optimal (less Input checking):

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G))
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl))
    {
        DoSomethingA();
    }
    else
    {
        DoSomethingB();
    }
}
```

EDIT 1:

If you have created all your MultiHotkey2, ~3 objects the check looks like this.

```
if (CheckTripleHotKey(_multiHotKey3)
{
    DoSomethingA();
}
else if (CheckDoubleHotKey(_multiHotKey2)
{
    DoSomethingB();
}
```

Need more details on what you have for a more specific answer.
If you have a lot of multihotkey objects, you probably want to iterate through them instead of checking one by one.

Comment: I have a lot of different combos first method only works for small count of functions, I updated my answer for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to use Unity's Input System Package. It makes easier to handle multiple key inputs.

Here it is:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.4/manual/index.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).